# MAMP unable to start servers (mysql,apache)

Tags: c++, mysql, apache, mamp

I've been trying to start mysql and apache servers locally on my machine for a school homework with the help of MAMP3.2.1 but everytime I open MAMP, i get these errors: [image]

[image]

From what i gathered from the net, this error appears when I'm installing 32bit software on a 64bit machine. Another report pointed on the error being caused by not having miscrosoft's visual c++ redistributable 2015 installed. I did that, but the error didn't go away. MAMP's only version for windows (I'm having 8.1) is 3.2.1 so I can't swap versions. Really any help would be much appreciated

Edit: I can't even intall the redistr packages right:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Universal CRT which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 failed to install or is missing.

Download the Visual C++ Redistributable:

For Windows 64-bit

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/c/b/8cb4af84-165e-4b36-978d-e867e07fc707/vc_redist.x64.exe)

For Windows 32-bit

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/b/3/9b3d2920-49f7-4e76-a55c-d72b51e44537/vc_redist.x86.exe)

Run the vc_redist.x64.exe (64-bit) or vc_redist.x86.exe (32-bit) to install it and it should work fine